# Getting error - Objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: javascript, reactjs

ChartProvider is generating list of charts acc to config file. I am trying to render all charts in MainComponent.

I am getting error: **"Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons."**

MainComponent:

```
var React = require('React');
var Chart = require('ChartProvider');

var MainComponent = React.createClass({    
    render: function () {
        return (
           <div>
              {Chart}
           </div>
         );
     }
 });
```

ChartProvider.js

```
var item = config.wList.map(function(widget, index) {     
       return ( 
                  <ChartComponent width="500px" height="400px"         
                   options={{title: widget.title}} /> 
           );          
       });
module.exports = item ;
```

Config.js file contains data:

```
module.exports = {
        wList : [ {
          title : "Average(Kbps)",
        }, {
          title : "Average DL(Kbps)",
        }, {
          title : "DL",
        }, 
        {
          title : "Minutes",         
        }, {
          title : "Cell",        
        }, {
          title : "UL",      
        }] 
      };
```

Comment: heres a pen that works, see if you can repro your problem with a fork.  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rWxyyv?editors=1010

Comment: @skav Thanks. Now there is no error.

Answer (score 0):

You export from a module via `module.exports`, not `module.export`:

```
module.exports = item;
```

In your code, `module.exports` is an empty object, which cannot be rendered and leads to the error message you are seeing.

---

Unrelated to that, you don't close your `<ChartComponent>`. Add a `/` to the end to fix this:

```
<ChartComponent width="500px" height="400px" options={{title: widget.title}} />
```